# Function to create msisdn from number and international prefix

Tags: php

I have a phone number (0891234567) and the international prefix (353), I need to match them with a list of phone numbers in the msisdn format (353891234567).

Now, for different countries I have to use different functions but I have to work on several countries and I would like to know if there is a library to do this.

Does somebody know where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Geolocation API you will get the location based on that able to bind the country code with the mobile number

post your code may get any idea about your task